# Hashing trick with random forest in scala

Tags: random-forest, apache-spark, scala

I am trying to perform a hashing trick and then a random forest with scala. I have the following code:

```
val documents: RDD[Seq[String]] = sc.textFile("hdfs:///tmp/new_cromosoma12v2.csv").map(_.split(",").toSeq)

val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
val tf: RDD[Vector] = hashingTF.transform(documents)

val splits = tf.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))

val numClasses = 3
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
val numTrees = 10 
val featureSubsetStrategy = "auto" 
val impurity = "gini"
val maxDepth = 8
val maxBins = 32

**val trainingData2=LabeledPoint(1.0,trainingData.collect())**

val model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData2, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo, numTrees, featureSubsetStrategy, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
```

But I have the error

found   : Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
 required: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector

in the bold line.

Do you know how I can solve it?

Thank you,

Laia

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the error message:

```
found : Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] required: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
```

"found" is the type of object that it came across, "required" is the type of the object that the function accepts. The types look mostly the same ( org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector ) but the first is Array[X] and the second is X.

Why? Because trainingData.collect() gives you the RDD as an array of objects in the array.

What you probably want to do instead is `map`, to turn each vector into a LabeledPoint, instead of trying to turn the whole RDD into a single LabeledPoint.

Answer (score 0):

`LabeledPoint` expects: `LabeledPoint(label: Double, features: Vector)`

when you execute `val trainingData2=LabeledPoint(1.0,trainingData.collect())` you're actually getting all the Rows in your trainingData set so you will have `Array(Row(???), Row(???), ???)` but what you need is to apply `def transformToLabeledPoint(vector: Vector) = LabeledPoint(1.0, vector)`, you can either apply a map on your trainingData or create a UDF and apply it to your trainingData, for instance:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.SQLTransformer
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((1.0,100.0),(2.0,200.0))).toDF("id", "value")

spark.udf.register("setLabel", (label: Double, x: Seq[Double]) => LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(x.toArray)))

val labeledTrainingData = new SQLTransformer()
    .setStatement("SELECT setLabel(1.0, array(*)) AS points FROM __THIS__")
    .transform(df)
val labeledRDD = labeledTrainingData.rdd.map(_(1).asInstanceOf[LabeledPoint])
```